# NSTimer userInfo Bad Access exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I got a problem with the `NSTimer` and the `userInfo`.
In [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/) Apple writes that the system keeps a strong reference to the Timer (and therefore the userInfo?) though sometimes when I'm trying to access parts of the userInfo object I'm getting a *Bad Access exception*. (Afaik that means something really bad happened)

Without further ado, here's how my object looks like that I pass to the userInfo:

```
@interface MyObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) u_int8_t cmd;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *_id;

@end
```

And here's how I set the Timer:

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(someMethod:) userInfo:message repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] myTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

The method that gets triggered when the Timer fires

```
-(void) someMethod:(NSTimer *)timer{
    MyObject* mObject = [timer userInfo];
    u_int8_t cmd = mObject.cmd; // This works
    NSNumber *_id = mObject._id; // Bad access
}
```

Note: The userInfo itself isn't nil. Neither is the `u_int8_t` nil or whatsoever. But as soon as I try to access the `NSNumber` object I'm receiving the following exception (not necessarily every time):

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
```

What happens if I add a `strong` property to the NSNumber object? Would this fix the issue and why? Why does this problem happen in the first place?

Comment: You are accessing properties that are different from your header definition, can you update your code?

Comment: @TomášLinhart you're right - just updated it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `NSNumber` is an object you need to use the `strong` attribute, which is the default, so change the `@property` declaration to:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *_id;
```

And using `_id` as the identifier is a bad idea as `id` is an Objective-C keyword, and you will likely confuse yourself at some point.

Comment: Just to understand the issue: Does this mean that ARC basically recycles the NSNumber object of the userInfo object but not the object itself?

Comment: Yes basically, however the bad thing is that it keeps a dangling pointer to the `NSNumber` object in the `userInfo` dictionary, which is the cause of the exception as the object is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

The property declaration is wrong.
`NSNumber` is an object. The property type must be strong or copy.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *_id;
```